# How to get started with plain TeX

Tags: pstricks, plain-tex

I am using TeX Live 2010 on Windows 7. I have no experience to compile a plain TeX input file.

1. Is my input file below correct?

   ```
   % gettingstarted.tex
   \input pstricks
   \topmargin=-72.27pt
   \oddsidemargin=-72.27pt
   \paperwidth=72.27pt
   \paperheight=72.27pt
   \parindent=0pt
   \special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}

   \pspicture(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
   \psframe(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
   \endpspicture

   \bye
   ```
2. What is the plain TeX compiler I must execute to get DVI output? And what is the syntax?

---

I have tried using `tex gettingstarted.tex` and I got the following errors:

[image]

Comment: I _strongly_ suggest you start simple with plain TeX, reading _The TeXbook_ and working up from basic examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use pdftex, if you want to profit from e-TeX extensions; on TeX Live it's available for DVI output as `etex` or, from the command line,

```
pdftex --output-format=dvi
```

Plain TeX has not many page format parameters: the upper left corner of the type block is 1in from the left edge and 1in from the upper edge of the paper.

In order to shift the text block it's necessary to either modify the output routine or to set `\hoffset` and `\voffset`. So

```
\hoffset=-72.27truept
\voffset=-72.27truept
\special{papersize=72.27pt,72.27pt}
\hsize=72.27truept
\vsize=72.27truept

\parindent=0pt
\nopagenumbers

\input pstricks

\pspicture(72.27pt,72.27pt)
\psframe(72.27pt,72.27pt)
\endpspicture

\bye
```

Without `\nopagenumbers` you'd have the number "printed" outside the page area.

A modified output routine that makes unnecessary to act on `\hoffset` and `\voffset` is

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\xportoutput#1#2{%
  \shipout\vbox{\vglue#1\relax
    \moveright#2\vbox{\makeheadline\pagebody\makefootline}}%
  \advancepageno
  \ifnum\outputpenalty>-\@MM \else\dosupereject\fi}
\catcode`@=12
\output{\xportoutput{-72.27truept}{-72.27truept}}
```

One can change the two parameters to `\xportoutput`, for example to adapt the position of the text block to A4 paper. The arguments are respectively the horizontal and the vertical displacements with respect to the default reference point. It's better to use `truept` in order not to apply the `\mag` factor.

Comment: That option is passed to **xcolor**. There's no **xcolor** for Plain.

Comment: It loads **xcolor** in LaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

Your input file is not right, as the various dimensions you've tried to use are not defined by the plain TeX format.

On the tool itself, it's just `tex`:

```
tex <filename>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
% gettingstarted.tex
\input pstricks
\parindent=0pt
\special{papersize=72.27pt,72.27pt}

\pspicture(72.27pt,72.27pt)
\psframe(72.27pt,72.27pt)
\endpspicture

\bye
```

Comment: `\leftskip=-in` and vor the vertical space I forgot it

Comment: xcolor is a LaTeX package!

Answer (score 2):

You could `\input eplain`* to have those commands available, with the exception of `\oddsidemargin` for which you could use (for the purposes of this particular question) the command `\leftmargin`.

[*eplain](http://www.tug.org/eplain/)