# Syntax Highlighting for Plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex, highlighting

I would like to find out what options there are for applying syntax highlighting to Plain TeX, to turn Plain TeX documents into highlighted HTML.

The aim is to facilitate sharing tracked changes to the Plain TeX document.  The document I wish to work with is fairly simple, but it does hand define several fonts, a bibliography environment, and make heavy use of `\halign` macros.  Some automatic or semi-automatic handling of these would be an advantage.  At a pinch I could do this with a `sed` script, but I would rather save myself some time.

Pygments does not seem to have support for Plain TeX.  Emacs' AUCTeX has `TeX-mode` for Plain TeX, but although I seem to recall that it is possible to export HTML from AUCTeX, I cannot recall any details.

Comment: I'd try to look at ConTeXt's verbatim-like features (with syntax highlighting) together with xml export.  (I am by no means a ConTeXt expert, but I wouldn't be surprised if such a solution worked (maybe almost) out-of-the-box.)

Comment: You should be able to use the `listings` package to highlight plain TeX.

Comment: @Peter: It's not obvious to me that `listings` will help me get HTML output.

Comment: @mbork: Your thinking of [t-vim](http://modules.contextgarden.net/vim) (cf. [Code highlighting in ConTeXt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7789/code-highlighting-in-context)), I take it?  That might work; I'll look into it.  I guess I should upgrade my version of Context.

Comment: I have an idea. If I'm not mistaken, `Vim` can highlight both plain TeX and LaTeX. Open your file with `Vim`, make sure the plain TeX syntax is selected, then use this magic trick: `:TOhtml` . The color scheme together with your file will be exported to a `html` file right in your `Vim` buffer. `:)`

Comment: @Paulo: That works.  The output is pretty ghastly HTML, all colour and font changes woven into the body with FONT tags, no CSS in sight, and a really ghastly choice of colours.  But it's good enough, I think, and I guess it is exactly the same output as I would get using the Context t-vim -> XML -> HTML route but easier.  Can you post this as an answer so that we can close this question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<sup>*Converting my comment to an answer.* `:)`</sup>

There is a plugin shipped with recent versions of `Vim` called `2html.vim`. The idea is to export the current buffer - including the color scheme - to HTML. For example, I'll use Herbert's code from [How to get started with plain TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23353/how-to-get-started-with-plain-tex):

```
% gettingstarted.tex
\input pstricks
\parindent=0pt
\special{papersize=72.27pt,72.27pt}

\pspicture(72.27pt,72.27pt)
\psframe(72.27pt,72.27pt)
\endpspicture

\bye
```

To use this plugin, put `Vim` in the normal mode and type:

```
:TOhtml
```

[image: Vim]

A new file named `yourcode.ext.html` is generated. The output is as follows:

[image: Output]

If I'm not mistaken, the choice of colors is related to the editor color scheme.

The generated HTML is full of inline styles. If you want a better output, I found the following entries to be added to your `_vimrc` file:

```
let html_use_css = 1 " Replaces the inline styles by CSS stylesheets. Values: 0 or 1
let html_number_lines = 0 " Shows line numbers. Values: 0 or 1
let html_no_pre = 1 " Don't wrap lines. Values: 0 or 1
```

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: I must have a really old version of 2html.vim - the HTML I get gives a completely different header.  But the output is useful and most definitely helps, so accepted.  I've written a small script to turn the font/color tag/attributes into span/class, which is far easier than writing a highlighter from scratch.  I'll post the code if there is any interest.

Comment: @Charles: `TOHtml` has an option to use CSS instead of raw font attributes. See `:he TOHtml` for details.

Comment: Actually Paulo aleady mentions it. Use `let html_use_css =1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing with emacs. Load the code into emacs and do `M-x ps-print-buffer-with-faces`. It will print a postscript image of the buffer.