# Use minted for plain-text? (without syntax-highlighting)

Tags: verbatim, minted, highlighting

I'm possibly too lazy to find how to do it without minted, but since I already use minted **and I want top keep it's styles it applies to code boxes** (like background color, the line break features, `typewriter-style`/same-width text etc.), I want to do it with minted.

`\inputminted` requires the language as the first *required* argument, so I cannot omit it, and *pygments* does not have a "plain text" style option as it seems, so I cannot use that there.

So when i just want to input a plain-text block with minted (without any syntax-highlighting), how can I do that?

**Use case:** I could not find a proper syntax highlighting for arbitrary console output (on GitHub you e.g. have `console` for Markdown.)

I have [found this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45847/98645), but it's not about minted, but getting HTML code or so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh forget it, there is apparently a "language"/lexer [called `text`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131323/turn-off-syntax-highlighting-in-minted). So stupid I could not find it [as it is not listed on the pygments home page](https://pygments.org/languages/).

I'll close this as a dupe.